# Python argparse a list input

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

The code below accepts command line arguments for `mode` such as `-m fizz` and `-m fizz bazz`. This, as expected, passes the arguments to the main function as `['fizz', 'bazz']` (for the second example above). It seems user-unfriendly to pass command line arguments with spaces, so I'd like argparse to accept a comma-separated list e.g. `-m fizz,bazz` or `-m ['fizz','bazz']`. How can I modify the code below to do this? Thanks!

```
import agrparse
...
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mode", nargs="*",
                    default=["fizz", "bazz", "razmataz"],
                    help="Comma separated list of mode(s) to use, e.g."
                    "[\"fizz\", \"bazz\"]")
main(parser.parse_args())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple script that prints `sys.argv` I get

```
1014:~/mypy$ python echoargv.py -m ['fizz','bazz']
['echoargv.py', '-m', '[fizz,bazz]']
1014:~/mypy$ python echoargv.py -m fizz,bazz
['echoargv.py', '-m', 'fizz,bazz']
1015:~/mypy$ python echoargv.py -m fizz, bazz
['echoargv.py', '-m', 'fizz,', 'bazz']
1016:~/mypy$ python echoargv.py -m ['fizz', 'bazz']
['echoargv.py', '-m', '[fizz,', 'bazz]']
1016:~/mypy$ python echoargv.py -m fizz bazz
['echoargv.py', '-m', 'fizz', 'bazz']
```

That's what your `parser` has to work with.

The last case, where each string is a separate item in the `sys.argv` is simplest, and is what your `nargs='*'` is designed to handle.  It should return  `Namespace(mode = ['fizz','bazz'])`

You have 2 options.  You could clean up `sys.argv` before passing it to the `parser`.  Or you could look at the `args.mode` attribute after parsing, and clean it up as needed.

For example `'fizz,bazz'` could be split on `,`.  `'[fizz,bazz]'` requires stripping off the `[]` first.  Others require removing extra `,`'.

You could do this splitting and cleanup in a custom Action class, but it isn't going to save you any work.

---

A custom `type` could also be used to split strings

```
In [170]: def foolist(astring):
    alist=astring.strip('[').strip(']').split(',')
    alist = [a.strip() for a in alist if len(a)]
    return alist

In [171]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [172]: p.add_argument('-m',type=foolist,nargs='*')
Out[172]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-m'], dest='m',...

In [173]: p.parse_args(['-m','one','two'])
Out[173]: Namespace(m=[['one'], ['two']])

In [174]: p.parse_args(['-m','one,two'])
Out[174]: Namespace(m=[['one', 'two']])

In [175]: p.parse_args(['-m','[one, two]'])
Out[175]: Namespace(m=[['one', 'two']])
```

A down side to this that the lists are nested.  The default `nargs` could be used, but it  wouldn't allow the regular space delimited lists.  But there are standard python ways of flattening a nested list.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this can be handled after parsing by calling `args.mode[0].split(',')`, but I'm looking for a solution where argparse can be specified to handle the comma-separated input on its own.

Comment: Then you have to create a custom Action that can do the splitting.  There aren't any predefined bells or whistles that will do it for you.  Look at the example in the docs, print the `values` for your desired arguments, and process those.

Comment: I added a `type` example